# Axler "Linear Algebra Done Right" Exercise 6.B.13

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, inner-products

This exercise appears in Section 6.B "Orthonormal Bases" in *Linear Algebra Done Right* by Sheldon Axler.  Inner product spaces, norms, orthogonality, and orthonormal bases have been introduced.

The unofficial [solution manual](https://linearalgebras.com/6b.html) I am using presents a somewhat involved proof of this exercise that involves induction and the Gram-Schmidt procedure, which I will not reproduce here.  However, I arrived at an alternative proof that is much simpler in my opinion.  I would like to check if my proof is correct.

---

$(V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ is an inner product space over the field $\mathbb{F}$, which stands for either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.  (Axler, pp. 4, 167)

> 13. Suppose $v_1, \dotsc, v_m$ is a linearly independent list in $V$.  Show that there exists $w \in V$ such that $\langle w, v_j \rangle > 0$ for all $j \in \{1, \dotsc, m\}$.  (Axler, p. 191)

Proof.  Let $U = \operatorname{span}(v_1, \dotsc, v_m)$.  Consider the linear map $\phi : U \to \mathbb{F}^m$ defined by
$$
\phi(u) = (\langle u, v_1 \rangle, \dotsc, \langle u, v_m \rangle).
$$
We show that $\phi$ is injective.  Suppose that $u \in U$ and $\phi(u) = 0$.  Then,
$$
\langle u, v_1 \rangle = \dotsb = \langle u, v_m \rangle = 0.
$$
Since $u \in \operatorname{span}(v_1, \dotsc, v_m)$,
we have $\langle u, u \rangle = 0$, so $u = 0$.  Hence, $\phi$ is injective.  But $\dim U = \dim \mathbb{F}^m = m$, so $\phi$ is surjective.  Choose $w \in U$ such that
$$
\phi(w) = (1, \dotsc, 1).
$$
Therefore, $\langle w, v_j \rangle = 1 > 0$ for all $j \in \{1, \dotsc, m\}$.

Comment: Your proof is  correct.

Comment: Another proof can be made by GS but no induction. There is $w_k$ such that $\langle w_k,v_k\rangle =1$ and $w_k\perp v_l $ for $l\neq k.$ Just apply GS to $v_1,\ldots,v_{k-1} ,v_{k+1},\ldots,v_n,v_k.$ Then $w=w_1+w_2+\ldots +w_n$ satisfies $\langle w,v_k\rangle =1.$

Comment: Yet another proof: let $t>0$ be sufficiently small, $u_1=v_1$ and $u_j=v_1+tv_j$ for $j\ge2$. Then $\langle u_1,u_j\rangle>0$ for each $j$. Define a linear map $\phi$ on $V$ by $\phi(v_j)=u_j$ and let $w=\phi^\ast(v_1)$. Then $\langle w,v_j\rangle=\langle \phi^\ast(v_1),v_j\rangle=\langle v_1,\phi(v_j)\rangle=\langle u_1,u_j\rangle>0$.

Comment: Also, ${\cal R} V^T = {\cal R} V^T V$ and $V^T V$ is positive definite.

Comment: Another way to state what you did: form the reciprocal basis $v^1,\dotsc,v^m$ in $U$ and choose $w = v^1 + \dotsb + v^m$.